# Perl m// operator inexplicably fails to match a simple regex

Tags: regex, perl, pcre

Today, while writing a regex to match a prompt output in order to interact with a program through IPC::RUN, I came across an inexplicable failure in matching a simple regex.

```
$ perl -E 'say "OK" if "mbox user@testdomain.it> " =~ /mbox\s+.*@.*> /s'
$
$ perl -E 'say "OK" if "mbox user@testdomain.it> " =~ /mbox\s+.*@t.*> /s'
OK
$
```

I thought it could be a problem of interpolation of «@» as a sigil, but

```
$ perl -E 'say "OK" if "mbox user@testdomain.it> " =~ /mbox\s+.*\@.*> /s'
$
```

It's so simple I can't seem to understand where the problem may lie.

Perl version is 5.10.1 on an Ubuntu 10.4

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you were on the right track but looking at interpolation in the wrong place.

Consider what happens to the `@` in your string rather than your regex.

Comment: As I said, it was so simple it was staring me right in the face.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape the @ in the string to be matched or use single quotes - this is awkward from the shell.
Also, you had an extra space at the end of your regex.

```
perl -E 'say "OK" if "mbox user@testdomain.it> " =~ /mbox\s+.*@.*> /s'  # Yours
perl -E 'say "OK" if "mbox user\@testdomain.it> " =~ /mbox\s+.*@.*>/s'  # Working
```

Comment: There is a space at the end of the search to match, too, so that isn't part of the problem.

Comment: Actually the space at the end of the regex was correct. Correct for the interpolation. Thank you as well

Comment: Not awkward in this case, just swap the use of ' and ".

Answer (score 3):

Try this (putting an extra \ before the @ in your string):

```
$ perl -E 'say "OK" if "mbox user\@testdomain.it> " =~ /mbox\s+.*\@.*> /s'
```

Comment: @FulvioScapin Alternatively, use single quotes around `mbox user@testdomain.it> ` although that's a little more difficult to do with command-line perl -E where you have the whole command in single quotes.